# How to download json from db through procedure in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a button with dynamic action and type - execute js, js run the proccess which starts a procedure
Procedure try to download data - selected from db and converted to clob and after to blob.
File don't download, nothing happened when i click to button
P.S. found solution for similiar task, but not working for me https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4159089/download-some-clob-contetnt-as-a-file

**Procedure Code**

```
create or replace procedure "CREATE_CODOGEN_JSON"
(target_table_param IN VARCHAR2)
is
l_blob_content blob;
lol clob;
v_dest_offset integer := 1;
v_src_offset integer := 1;
v_lang_context  integer := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
v_warning       integer := DBMS_LOB.WARN_INCONVERTIBLE_CHAR;
BEGIN
SELECT 
to_clob(
    json_object(
'task_id' VALUE TARGET_TABLE))
into lol 
from UKDA.CODOGEN_META_TABLES
WHERE TARGET_TABLE = 'rv_lol';

dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob_content, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
sys.htp.init;
sys.OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/json', FALSE, 'UTF-8');
sys.HTP.p('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.getlength(lol));
sys.HTP.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'||'FILE_NAME.json'||'"');
dbms_lob.converttoblob(
    dest_lob    => l_blob_content,
    src_clob    => lol,
    amount      => DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE,
    dest_offset => v_dest_offset,
    src_offset  => v_src_offset,
    blob_csid   => DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID,
    lang_context=> v_lang_context,
    warning     => v_warning
);
sys.WPG_DOCLOAD.download_file(l_blob_content);
DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY (l_blob_content);
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
end;
```

Comment: Do you mean a process?

Comment: @FilipDegenhart , i start procedure from proccess

Comment: Oh sorry overread that. Are you not able to do it only with a ajax callback?

Comment: @FilipDegenhart yeah, but nothing, found some other way, maybe it help
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeapi/APEX_DATA_EXPORT.html#GUID-F195C61B-30DA-4462-93A3-465BCA6FCB78

Comment: This will not work as a dynamic action. You need to invoke a new request in another page. In the example you mention it is done in a new page. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie, i tried just now, but still get the same result, script outputs json(alert) and does not download it

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting relational data to json and downloading it then you should look at using `APEX_DATA_EXPORT`. The method you're describing is the "old" way - this can be done natively in later versions.
It's a lot less code, no need to handle lobs and conversion

Here is an example - implement it in a page process:

```
DECLARE
    l_context         apex_exec.t_context; 
    l_print_config    apex_data_export.t_print_config;
    l_export          apex_data_export.t_export;
    l_report_format   apex_data_export.t_format;
BEGIN
    l_context := apex_exec.open_query_context(
        p_location    => apex_exec.c_location_local_db,
        p_sql_query   => q'!select empno, ename, job from emp!' );
    l_report_format := apex_data_export.c_format_json;
    l_export := apex_data_export.export (
        p_context         => l_context,
        p_format          => l_report_format);
    apex_exec.close( l_context );
    apex_data_export.download( p_export => l_export );
EXCEPTION
    when others THEN
        apex_exec.close( l_context );
        raise;
END;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get a message with json, but not file, although i haven't print. When i create a new page, where button redirect and start proccess, i see json in html

Comment: Can you create a small test case on apex.oracle.com ? Request a new workspace just for this stack overflow issue and share the credentials. I'm happy to take a look.